# Process runs very slowly compared to PowerShell

Tags: vb.net, process

I'm using a small script called `ffprobe.exe` (part of the FFmpeg library) to read metadata from a video file.

Here's my code:

```
'Setup the process
Dim Proc As New Process()
With Proc.StartInfo
    .FileName = "C:\ffmpeg.exe"
    .UseShellExecute = False
    .CreateNoWindow = True
    .RedirectStandardOutput = True
    .RedirectStandardError = True
    .Arguments = "C:\testVideoFile.mp4"
End With

'Start the process and wait for it to exit
Proc.Start()

'Set the process to be high-priority
Proc.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High

'Listen for process output
ProcessOutput = ""
AddHandler Proc.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf Proc_OutputDataReceived
AddHandler Proc.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf Proc_OutputDataReceived
AddHandler Proc.Exited, AddressOf Proc_Exited
Proc.BeginOutputReadLine()
Proc.BeginErrorReadLine()
Proc.EnableRaisingEvents = True

'Wait for the process to exit
PSProc.WaitForExit()
```

This code works just fine. The problem is that it takes way longer to run than it does in PowerShell. PowerShell runs the script seemingly instantly, but in my application the code above takes anywhere from 1 to 3 seconds to execute.

I know this question has been asked a lot, but I really couldn't find a definitive answer on why it takes so long.

Am I doing something wrong or is this just the way it is?

Comment: `Process.Start` is basically like running an app from the command prompt. That's what you should be comparing to. If that's quicker, then you have something to look for in your code. Otherwise, you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I apologize my wording was unclear. I have edited my post.

Comment: Running ffmpeg.exe via either powershell or command line won't have the overheads of those event handlers you got in your app.  How are they effecting your execution times?

Comment: @Hursey That's a good idea. I just tried removing them, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be any better. It's worth noting that this particular command only outputs about 20 lines, so I really don't think that's bogging it down.